# webpack-dev-server not working with proxy IIS Express after Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: c#, typescript, webpack, iis-express, webpack-dev-server

After installing Windows 10 Creators Update `webpack-dev-server` does not work anymore. What happens is that I start IIS Express and it works like normal. When I then try to start `webpack-dev-server` with a proxy to the IIS Express I get the following error in Visual Studio:

> The program '[14752] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895
>   (0x800703e9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Turned out to be a stack overflow exception and not the IIS at all. I also did a git pull but since I had a lot of other errors with my screens etc after Creators Update I thought it was related. A hint might be that -2147023895 is quite close to Int32.MinValue (-2,147,483,648).

**Original:**

Got it working but it is painfully slow. In `VS -> Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Tick "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"`

[image]

I also tried deleting the `.vs` folder and bind the application to a new port but this did not help.